# Inner Class Constructor

Tags: apex, salesforcedx, class

My Scenario is that I need to call the inner class Constructor from another class, Let me know how can I achieve this.

Codes:

```
public class A {

    // Inner Class
    public class W {

        Integer y;
        String j;
        //Constructor
       W(Integer i, String g){
            this.y = i;
            this.j = j;

        }
    }
```

How can I access the Constructor W from another class B:

```
public class B {

    A a = new A();

    a.W.W(10,l);

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just make sure the inner class constructor is public then:

```
A.W myW = new A.W(10, 1);
```